# "Negative time" error when building with Maven (in Netbeans)

Tags: maven, netbeans

Using Maven inside Netbeans 8.0.2 (3.0.5) I get the following (strange) error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project JConnect4Server: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Negative time -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project JConnect4Server: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Negative time
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Negative time
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
    at java.io.File.setLastModified(File.java:1427)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask$1.registered(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructure.registerFile(WebappStructure.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFiles(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFiles(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.handeWebAppSourceDirectory(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.performPackaging(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:479)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildExplodedWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:412)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    ... 20 more
```

First of all the error message makes no sense to me - but what is really strange is that building and packaging the application on commandline just works out fine, the problem occurs only when Maven gets called within Netbeans 8.0.2.

The pom itself looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.dhbw.mbfl</groupId>
    <artifactId>JConnect4Server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>JConnect4Server</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sa_viergewinnt_core-mvn-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.github.com/FlorianLoch/sa_viergewinnt_core/gh-pages/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>    

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.dhbw.mbfl</groupId>
            <artifactId>JConnect4Lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there any more experienced Maven user who can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Update: JDK used by Netbeans and Maven is: 1.8.0_25, JDK used outside the VM (where packaging works just fine) is 1.8.0_31 (I read some stuff on whether this might be a JDK bug...).

Update: I updated the JDK in the VM, the error stays the same.

Comment: Can you launch the command with -e to get the error stacktrace?

Comment: Of course, I should have done that right away...

Comment: So it looks like the same kind of issue as described here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-255. Comment there states: "This occurs when I have in src/main/webapp/ files with date 1970-01-01 and it's a rather hard to discover this."

Comment: I am not sure if it is the same problem... When invoking ````find ./ -mtime +200```` I do not find any files - and if there were files from "timestamp 0" I should find them this way, should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I found the error. It is caused by a JDK bug/problem resulting in a FileNotFound-Exception. This would also explain why the error just occurs using Windows.

To put it simply, it just didn't work because there is a single space in the path of the files... So moving the project solves the problem. Working with Mac OS the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: This is not the cause of this error on my Mac running maven in Docker.  The error appears to be sporadic.  In my case the error terminates a data analysis on the first try but on a restart of the analysis (with no alterations whatsoever) the error is not present and the analysis completes.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why the problem occurs, but found out the solution. The error occurs because, one or more file that you are trying to build, has a negative time.(`file.getLastModified()` returns a negative value). If its a huge project, might be hard to track which of them has gone wrong.

The code below might help:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class ModifyAll {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<File> folderList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

        File folder = new File("D:/Rakhu/Copy/projectfolder/src");
        FileVO baseFileVO = segregateFiles(folder);
        fileList.addAll(baseFileVO.getFileList());
        folderList.addAll(baseFileVO.getFolderList());

        for (int i = 0; i < folderList.size(); i++) {
            FileVO thisVO = segregateFiles(folderList.get(i));
            fileList.addAll(thisVO.getFileList());
            folderList.addAll(thisVO.getFolderList());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            Date dte = new Date();
            long milliSeconds = dte.getTime();
            System.out.println("Setting Time For " + fileList.get(i) + " as " + milliSeconds);
            fileList.get(i).setLastModified(milliSeconds);
        }
        System.out.println("Succesfully Modified..!!!");
    }

    public static FileVO segregateFiles(File folder) {
        List<File> folderList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                fileList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
            } else {
                folderList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(listOfFiles[i]);
        }
        return new FileVO(fileList, folderList);
    }
}



FileVO.java
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileVO {
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<File> folderList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FileVO(List<File> fileList, List<File> folderList) {
        this.fileList = fileList;
        this.folderList = folderList;
    }

    public List<File> getFileList() {
        return fileList;
    }

    public void setFileList(List<File> fileList) {
        this.fileList = fileList;
    }

    public List<File> getFolderList() {
        return folderList;
    }

    public void setFolderList(List<File> folderList) {
        this.folderList = folderList;
    }
}
```