# Getting :Negative Time error while Unpack Zip via Maven Dependency

Tags: java, maven, build

I am getting following exception on **windows** (other systems it works fine)
with `Maven 3.5.2` and `JDK 1.8`.
So, the maven build is trying to unzip a dependency, which it is not able to.
Manually unzipping it is successful.
There are no spaces in the path.

Any Suggestions?

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution unpack-zip-dependencies of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.3:unpack failed: Negative time
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
    at java.io.File.setLastModified (File.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.extractFile (AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipUnArchiver.extractFileIfIncluded (AbstractZipUnArchiver.java:181)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501034/negative-time-error-when-building-with-maven-in-netbeans

Comment: @neuo Yes, Saw that already, however he did had a 'space' in the path. I don't. That's why I specifically specified that I don't have a space in the path

Comment: Please update your [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) cause you are using an really ancient version...

Comment: @khmarbaise ahh.. can that be a problem? unfortunately I can't update that, however let me try and check if that is an issue.

Comment: I recommend to update cause there had been a ton of fixes between 2011 and today...If you can't ? Why can't you update to a new version of a plugin? Does not make sense in particular if there is a problem...

Comment: yeah, I mean I can't. I will have to raise this in a product support forum that I am using, and it will go through multiple sprints before it gets updated.